# Thread class that uses std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, pointers

I have implemented a class which encapsulates a thread of execution and provides an interface to send messages to it. It is based largely on an [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/prefer-using-active-objects-instead-of-n/225700095?pgno=3) written by Herb Sutter in 2010. It also uses the pImpl idiom as described by Scott Meyers in *Effective Modern C++*.

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42115613/820657) on Stack Overflow from a guy with a high reputation recently stated that storing an `std::thread` in a `unique_ptr` was utter nonsense.

Now I'm wondering: Is there anything wrong with my implementation? Are there ways in which it could be improved?

thread.h

```
/**
 * \brief   Encapsulates a thread of execution and provides an interface to send messages to it.
 *
 * \details The object owns its own private thread and runs all of its work on that private thread. 
 *
 *          Calls on an active object should always be non-blocking asynchronous messages, so when a caller invokes
 *          the operation to send a message, the call just queues the message and returns immediately to the caller.
 *
 *          The thread mainline is an event-driven message pump that dequeues and executes the messages one at a 
 *          time on the private thread itself. Because the messages are processed sequentially, they are atomic with
 *          respect to each other. And because the object's private data is only accessed from the thread, there is
 *          no need to take a mutex lock or perform other synchronization on the private shared state.
 *
 *          The lifetime of the thread is tied directly to the lifetime of the object itself.
 */
class Thread
{
public:
    /**
     * \brief Starts the thread and message pump.
     *
     * \param name The name of the thread. Required only to aid debugging.
     */
    Thread(const std::string& name);

    /**
     * \brief   Stops the thread and message pump.
     *
     * \details A sentinel message is added behind any messages already waiting in the queue to signal the thread
     *          to finish and then it joins with the thread to wait for it to drain the queue and end.
     *
     *          Note that this is the only blocking call from the viewpoint of the caller.
     */
    virtual ~Thread();

    /**
     * \brief Queues the given message.
     *
     * \param message The message to queue.
     *
     * \return None
     */
    void send(std::function<void()> message);

    /**
     * \brief Queues a mesage to stop the message pump. effectively causing the thread to run to completion.
     *
     * \return None
     */
    void stop();

    /**
     * \brief Returns whether or not the thread has terminated.
     *
     * \return True if the thread has terminated, false otherwise.
     */
    bool hasTerminated() const;

private:
    Thread();
    Thread(const Thread&);
    const Thread& operator=(const Thread&);

    /** Private implementation details. */
    struct Impl;
    const std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};
```

thread.cpp

```
/** Encapsulates the private implementation details of Thread. */
struct Thread::Impl
{
public:
    Impl(const std::string& name) :
        m_name(name),
        m_isDone(false),
        m_hasTerminated(false),
        m_queue(),
        m_thread()
    {
    }

    virtual ~Impl()
    {
    }

private:
    Impl();
    Impl(const Impl&);
    const Impl& operator=(const Impl&);

    /**
     * \brief The dispatch loop. Takes messages from the queue one at a time and processes them until it receives
     *        the sentinel message to terminate. If the queue is empty, it waits until a job is available.
     *
     * \return None
     */
    void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!m_isDone)
            {
                // wait until a job is available, then retrieve it and execute it on this thread
                std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> func = m_queue.pop();

                // execute the message
                (*func.get())();
            }
        }

        catch (const std::exception& ex)
        {
            // log error
        }

        catch (...)
        {
            // log error
        }

        m_hasTerminated = true;
    }

    /** The name of the thread. This is to aid debugging. */
    const std::string m_name;

    /** Flag to terminate the message pump. */
    bool m_isDone;

    /** Flag indicating the thread has terminated - i.e. run to completion. */
    std::atomic<bool> m_hasTerminated;

    /** The message queue. */
    SharedQueue<std::function<void()>> m_queue;

    /** The thread of execution that dequeues and executes the messages one at a time. */
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;

    friend class Thread;
};

Thread::Thread(const std::string& name) : m_impl(new Impl(name))
{
    // start the thread
    m_impl->m_thread = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread( [=]{ m_impl->run(); } ));
}

Thread::~Thread()
{
    // tell thread to exit if it hasn't already been told

    if (!m_impl->m_isDone)
    {
        send( [=]{ m_impl->m_isDone = true; } );
    }

    if (m_impl->m_thread->joinable())
    {
        // wait for the thread to terminate (i.e. run() to return)
        m_impl->m_thread->join();
    }
}

void Thread::send(std::function<void()> message)
{
    m_impl->m_queue.push(message);
}

void Thread::stop()
{
    // tell thread to exit
    send( [=]{ m_impl->m_isDone = true; } );
}

bool Thread::hasTerminated() const
{
    return m_impl->m_hasTerminated;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We're missing the definition of `SharedQueue`, which means we don't know whether `send()` can throw (e.g. `std::bad_alloc`) and therefore whether `~Thread()` can throw.  If it can, then we have a serious problem.

I don't think we can guarantee that `m_impl->m_thread->join()` won't throw either, so we need to handle that to ensure the destructor doesn't throw.

It's unfortunate that this has to be C++11 code, because C++20 gives us `std::jthread` and cancellation tokens to help implement the functionality we have here.

The missing `SharedQueue` also leaves us unable to reason about the memory model and cross-thread communication.  That's something vitally important for a thread object!

Prefer not to use catch-all lambda captures (i.e. `[=]`).  We need only capture `m_impl` (in C++11, I think that means capturing the `this` pointer; C++17 improves that).

I don't like the repetition of `send([=]{ m_impl->m_isDone = true; });` in the `Thread` destructor, when that can be more simply achieved by calling `stop()`; I think that's much clearer, too.